# Python:Syntax Error while using Lambda Function inside List

Tags: python, list, lambda

I am relatively new to python. I am trying to filter data in List using a Lambda, but the compiler gives me a syntax error for the commented code.

```
# documents = [(list(filter(lambda w:w if not  w in stop_words,movie_reviews.words(fileid))),category)
#         for category in movie_reviews.categories()
#         for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
#
documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)),category)
        for category in movie_reviews.categories()
        for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
```

The uncommented section works, but the commented section gives a syntax error. Any inputs what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x if y` expressions require an `else`. It's an expression which must return a value, and without `else` it's undefined what's supposed to happen in the event that the `if` condition does not apply.

At the very least you need:

```
w if w not in stop_words else None
```

(Also `x not in` is the preferred direct operation as opposed to `not x in`.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
w if not w in stop_words
```

This is the first half of a [ternary condition operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator), but it's missing the `else` block.

You actually don't need this operator at all, your lambda should look like this:

```
lambda w:not w in stop_words
```